# How to set color of toggle buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I have group of toggle buttons. They are very light and disappear in the background on poor monitors with a high brightness level.

[image]

How can I properly style them? I would prefer to assign them the *accent* or *primary* colors, the way you can do it for regular buttons.

In may case, the primary and accent colors are dark. So they text should become white (with some transparency). For regular buttons, it automatically works.

```
<div class="output-size">
  <mat-button-toggle-group>
    <mat-button-toggle value="letter">Letter</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="legal">Legal</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="a4">A4</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="a5">A5</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`matButtonToggle` does not support the `color` property like `matButton`.

You can use the css classes `.mat-button-toggle` and `.mat-button-toggle-checked` to style the different states.

With material theming you can extract whichever individual palettes you need from the theme and apply the backgrounds default-contrast color to the text color to achieve optimal contrast with light or dark colors.

Here is a **Stackblitz** with your `mat-button-toggle-group` example: [Stackblitz
    angular-t1k1x6](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1k1x6)

**Theming used**:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent);

@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {
  $primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($app-theme, accent);

  .mat-button-toggle {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    color: mat-color($primary, default-contrast);
  }

  .mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: mat-color($accent);
    color: mat-color($accent, default-contrast);
  }
}

// Include the mixin
@include mix-app-theme($app-theme);
```

Documents: [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very helpful. I had read that documentation page before but thought it would only apply to custom components. There was one more thing I needed to make it work: `@include mix-app-theme` must be added after `@include angular-material-theme` if you use a custom theme as I do.

Comment: Just in case somebody wanna do a complete theming in `primary` color for the `mat-button-toggle` I summarized (after some struggle) https://stackoverflow.com/a/53846456/325868

Comment: thank you for correcting/ completing the material specs.

Comment: Thx! This works great except that in my case, the hover color for the checked state is misbehaving: it only changes on the bottom part of the button, but the 10px top band of the button stays in the checked color. I am using Angular 10, so maybe there have been changes? Help welcome, but this is apparently a known issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14721

Comment: @bfredo123 just set the `color` property on `.mat-button-toggle button` element instead.

Comment: Thanks @zzeneg - it works! (I used the example code you have added in github ticket 14721)

Comment: thanks, this is just so ridiculous and another reason not to go for angular material. It also doesn't work anymore with the new version. Any idea why they do not support the color property?

Answer (score 12):

You can use this Three CSS Classes **.mat-button-toggle** and **.mat-button-toggle-checked** for two state of styles

HTML Code

```
<mat-button-toggle-group>
    <mat-button-toggle value="letter">Letter</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="legal">Legal</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="a4">A4</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="a5">A5</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

CSS Code - You must use !important

```
.mat-button-toggle{
    background-color: #306cee;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.mat-button-toggle:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #1100ff !important;    
}

.mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: #ec2c4c;
    color: #67ec79 !important;
}
```

Comment: using !important is a bad practice. better learn how to style components instead

Comment: @Enrico agreed but angular and material teams do make it hard and there is little to no documentation

Comment: What is the current 2024 feelings on using `ng-deep` to overcome Angular's css encapsulation? I know they've been saying for a while that it is supposed to be deprecated, but I have not seen an alternative offered

Answer (score 9):

```css
mat-button-toggle-group {
  box-shadow: none;
}

mat-button-toggle {
    border: 1px rgba(0,0,0,0) solid !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    z-index: 3 !important;
}

mat-button-toggle:hover {
    border: 1px #000 solid !important;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
}

.mat-button-toggle-checked {
   box-shadow: 0 0 30px #000 !important;
    border: 1px #000 solid !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
}

.mat-button-toggle-input {
    background-color: none !important;
    padding-left: 32px !important;
}
```

if you only want to change the style of checked

Answer (score 4):

Customizing the presentation using your own theme SASS, as the other answer shows, is a great short-term solution and gives you a lot of power over the presentation.  Ideally, this would become part of the core theme declarations, so that `<mat-button-toggle-group color="primary">` (perhaps also `<mat-button-toggle color="primary">`) just works without additional steps.

If you want to make this simpler in the future, give a thumbs-up to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7162).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following styles in styles.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-yellow, A200, A100, A400);

$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  .mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    color: mat-color($primary, default-contrast);
  }
}
```

ps: I assumed you have selected `scss` and `custom theme`

Answer (score 1):

First, add a class to your `mat-button-toggle` component:

```html
<mat-button-toggle class="custom-toggle" [checked]="isChecked">Option</mat-button-toggle>
```

Next, define this class in your CSS file and set the background color:

```css
.custom-toggle.mat-button-toggle-checked {
  background-color: #3498db; /* Background color when checked */
  color: #ffffff; /* Change text color if desired */
}
```

In the example above, the `custom-toggle` class is a custom class for the `mat-button-toggle` component, and it applies the specified style rules when the button is checked. Using this class, you can define different background colors or other style properties for the checked and unchecked states.

You can customize the CSS rules further to meet your specific design requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround may be something like:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group>
  <mat-button-toggle value="letter">
    <button mat-button color="primary" style="pointer-events:none;">
      Letter
    </button>
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="legal">
    <button mat-button color="accent" style="pointer-events:none;">
      Legal
    </button>
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this on your component style:

```css
.mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: var(--color-500); // set the wanted color
    color: white;
}
```