# Theming in Angular 6 (and 7) for Mat-button-toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I found the wonderful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159346/325868) how to customize the Material toggle button. I succeed to set the `background-color` and the `font-weight` the way I want with

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent);

@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {
  $primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($app-theme, accent);

.mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    font-weight: bold;
    color:mat-color($primary); // <=== does not work!!!
  }
}

// Include the mixin
@include mix-app-theme($app-theme);
```

But somehow the font itself remains on black - which is not the default color when using `color="primary"`.

Any idea how to include the `fore-color` as well - properly?

Comment: `.mat-button-toggle { 
    color: mat-color($primary);
  }`

Comment: Nope, does NOT help - remains the same black foreground color remains... at least in Angular 7.1.1.

Answer (score 6):

Thanx to @Akhi Akl I and looking into the themes I found the following solution for `mat-button-toggle` in color `primary`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent);

@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {
  $primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);

  .mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    font-weight: bold;

    .mat-button-toggle-label-content{
        color: $light-primary-text;
    }
  }
}

// Include the mixin
@include mix-app-theme($app-theme);
```

Answer (score 4):

try using this

```
.mat-button-toggle-label-content{
   color:mat-color($primary)
}
```

if you want change color of checked button only try this

```
.mat-button-toggle-checked {
   .mat-button-toggle-label-content{
       color:mat-color($primary)
    }
}
```

Comment: I getting closer - but not solving the issue :-/ First of all the CSS property is the correct one - I see the color of the font is changing - which is good. The bad news is that it changes to the wrong color :-( It changes to the `primary` color I already have set :-( Trying something like `$foreground: map-get($app-theme, foreground);` ...   `color:mat-color($foreground, text)` sets the text into the default foreground color =black. But I need the foreground color of `primary` for `buttons`. Any idea how to get it?

Comment: I am not getting what you want. If you can add a sample slackblitz project

Comment: See my answer - thx for pointing towards the proper direction :-)

Comment: Ok I now see what is your requirement. And always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Material you will also need to include this class
`.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard`

```
.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard .mat-button-toggle-label-content {
    line-height: 0px;
    padding: 4px 7px;
}
.mat-button-toggle{
    background-color: #B2B2B2;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: #48A808;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Manas Sahu, you're answering a question which is over 1 year old. Please try to answer new questions, this is more helpful. And please explain your answer. Don't answer with just a code block.