# Angular Material: Split button

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to make in Angular Material a split button? It should look similar to the [Bootstrap sample](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_split.asp) I tried:

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>... Black Forest</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>... Salted Caramel</button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy">
  <mat-button-toggle color="primary" (click)="doSomethingBig()">
    Tell me about Earl Gray Ice Cream
  </mat-button-toggle>

  <mat-button-toggle color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
    <mat-icon>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

My problems:

1. If I use the `legacy` as style for apperance than I have the strange effect that buttons background as transparent.
2. The option `color` is ignored completely. Is there a way to have different colors? Especially if I want to use two buttons of it in the same row than one could be `primary` and the other `accent`
3. If it's possible to change the background - is it possible to draw a border between the two buttons?

Comment: Maybe you can style your mat-select as a button by modifying its css and that can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular Material split buttons can be obtained on the basis of `mat-button-toggle-group` combined with some `css` definitions.

Check out the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpgqjf)

[image]

Please note that `mat-button-toggle` does not support the color property as other Material components do (see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159346/2358409).

Comment: Looks great - and little bit better than my approach to use `@mixin` style modification. Thx... clearly something I need to use next time.