# How to change background color and font color on selection in mAngular material toggle button

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am facing one issue. I need to change the background color and its font color when user will select the toggle button using Angular material. I am explaining my code below.

```
 <div class="btn-group">
            <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [value]="selectedVal" (change)="onValChange(group.value)" color="primary">
              <mat-button-toggle value="option1" style="border-right: none;width:127px">
                Option 1
              </mat-button-toggle>
              <mat-button-toggle value="option2" style="border-right: none;width:127px">
                Option 2
              </mat-button-toggle>
            </mat-button-toggle-group>
          </div>
```

The css code is given below.

```
:host .mat-button-toggle-group{
    border-radius: 20px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    z-index: 3 !important;
    color: #017cad !important;
}
:host .mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: #017cad !important;
    color: #f5f5f6;
}
```

As per my code the view looks like below.

[image: image1]

When I am selecting any one button it looks like below.

[image: image2]

If we see the above view then the some part of background is not filled with the color and also the text color I need to change to `white` after selection. The right view should looks like below.

[image: image3]

I need like above image the angular material toggle button should visible. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using themes. With material theming you can extract whichever individual palettes you need from the theme and apply the backgrounds default-contrast color to the text color to achieve optimal contrast with light or dark colors. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48159346/15439733